# Showing colored text in textfield

Tags: android

i am writing text to a EditText .Can in show text in multiple colors as the 
`android:textColor` 
shall change the color of the entire text.
kindly update

Comment: You want to put different colors on the text while the user add it or after the text is enterred?

Comment: as the user is entering text .as the user presses enter the next text that comes in the next line comes with a new color

Comment: You want a different color for each line of your EditText, is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are welcome to apply `ForegroundColorSpan` and/or `BackgroundColorSpan` to portions of your text.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RichText/Search) happens to apply `BackgroundColorSpan` (to highlight search results in a `TextView`), but the same principle holds for `ForegroundColorSpan` and an `EditText` widget.

```
  private void searchFor(String text) {
    TextView prose=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.prose);
    Spannable raw=new SpannableString(prose.getText());
    BackgroundColorSpan[] spans=raw.getSpans(0,
                                             raw.length(),
                                             BackgroundColorSpan.class);

    for (BackgroundColorSpan span : spans) {
      raw.removeSpan(span);
    }

    int index=TextUtils.indexOf(raw, text);

    while (index >= 0) {
      raw.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFF8B008B), index, index
          + text.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
      index=TextUtils.indexOf(raw, text, index + text.length());
    }

    prose.setText(raw);
  }
```